# How to specify several join conditions for 1:1 relationship in Doctrine 2

Tags: php, doctrine, doctrine-orm

Documentation states:

```
class Cart
{
    // ...

    /**
     * @OneToOne(targetEntity="Customer", inversedBy="cart")
     * @JoinColumn(name="customer_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $customer;

    // ...
}
```

This annotation represents such sql:

```
JOIN Customer c ON c.id = cart.customer_id
```

And the issue is that I need to add additional comparison there, like:

```
JOIN Customer c ON c.id = cart.customer_id AND c.anotherField = <constant>
```

Any solutions for that?

**UPD**:

the real additional condition I need for now is `<const> BETWEEN c.f1 AND c.f2`

Comment: Have you tried to specify second join column with `columnDefinition="enum('YOUR_CONSTANT')")` ?

Comment: You can use queryBuilder when making the query ?

Comment: Actually, the second condition is a bit more difficult - I thought it doesn't matter for *general* solution. For now I need `AND <const> BETWEEN c.f1 AND c.f2`

Comment: @zerkms the `JoinColumn` annotation isn't for defining queries, its for use when doctrine auto-generates the database schema, and for when it saves objects (to cascade updates and deletes if necessary). AFAIK, you can't achieve what you want easily

Comment: @Jaitsu: cannot agree with you - it is also used for retrieving related objects. In that case it is used for generating queries ;-)

Comment: actually @Jaitsu is kind of on the right track. JoinColumn isn't *meant* to be used with queries. if what you need is a query for related objects but with an extra condition, what is the query you are trying to achieve?

Comment: @jere: I have already given example. Let's say it is `SElECT l, c FROM location
INNER JOIN Customer c ON c.id = l.customer_id AND NOW() BETWEEN c.f1 AND c.f2
WHERE NOW() BETWEEN l.f1 AND l.f2`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you can use the `WITH` keyword to specify additional join conditions, as you can see in some of the [examples](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#dql-select-examples).

i think this should get you going:

```
SELECT l, c FROM location
INNER JOIN Customer c
WITH CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() BETWEEN c.f1 AND c.f2
WHERE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() BETWEEN l.f1 AND l.f2
```

i removed the `ON` clause because i think there's no need to explicitly specify the join's `ON` fields unless they are not the "standard" ones (id of each entity)

also notice the call to `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()` which translates into MySQL's `NOW()`. check out a list of other pretty useful aggregate functions and expresions [here](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.0.x/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#functions-operators-aggregates)

Comment: Doesn't really answer the question.  Say you only wanted active records, can you express that with the notation?  Or please explain how to use that blob of DQL to populate the property of an entity.

Answer (score 1):

There doesn't seem to be any solution to your problem that Doctrine could do auto-magically.

Since @ficuscr already gave you a solution for queries, there's only one more thing to handle - check your additional criteria and return the Customer instance in your getter on success and NULL on failure to meet additional criteria.

```
class Cart
{
    const VALUE = '<some_constant_value>';
    /**
     * @OneToOne(targetEntity="Customer", inversedBy="cart")
     * @JoinColumn(name="customer_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $customer;

    // ...

    /**
     * @return Customer|null
     */
    public function getCustomer()
    {
        if ($this->customer->getField1() <= self::VALUE
            && $this->customer->getField2() >= self::VALUE
        ) {
            return $this->customer;
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

If this was a One-To-Many relation, [Collection Filtering API](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/working-with-associations.html#filtering-collections) (a.k.a. Criteria) could be used to filter the collection created by the mappings:

```
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Criteria;

class Cart
{
    const VALUE = '<some_constant_value>';
    /**
     * @OneToMany(targetEntity="Customer", mappedBy="cart")
     */
    private $customers;

    // ...

    /**
     * @return Customer[]|ArrayCollection
     */
    public function getCustomers()
    {
        $expr = Criteria::expr();
        $criteria = Criteria::create()
            ->where($expr->andX(
                $expr->lte('field1', self::VALUE),
                $expr->gte('field2', self::VALUE)
            ));

        return $this->patientProblems->matching($criteria);
    }
}
```