# How to get instance of entity repository in the Form (Type) class in Symfony 2?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, doctrine-orm

Let's say I have ordinary `*Type` class:

```
class LocationType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add(...)
            ...
    }
}
```

and one of the fields is a `choice` type. The values that need to be used as choice items are supposed to be retrieved from the database (from some particular entity repository).

So the question is: how to get the repository in the `LocationType` class? Is passing it through the constructor the only way to get it?

**UPD**:

I know about `entity` type but unfortunately I cannot use it, because my property is not and cannot be defined as `one-to-one` relation due to very complex relation conditions that Doctrine doesn't support (yet?). See [How to specify several join conditions for 1:1 relationship in Doctrine 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9123264/how-to-specify-several-join-conditions-for-11-relationship-in-doctrine-2) for additional details

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can specify an entity field type as an option like so:

```
$builder
    ->add('foo', 'entity', array(
        'class'  => 'FooBarBundle:Foo',
        'query_builder' => function(\Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository $er) {
             return $er->createQueryBuilder('q')->orderBy('q.name', 'ASC');
         },
     ));
```

**EDIT**:
Actually the 'class' option is the only required field option. You can read a bit more about the entity field type here: http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/reference/forms/types/entity.html

Hope this helps.

**EDIT**:

Further to discussion below, here's an example

In the controller:

```
$entity = new Foo();
$type   = new FooType();

$er = $this->getDoctrine()
    ->getEntityManager()
    ->getRepository('FooBarBundle:Foo');

$form = $this->createForm($type, $entity, array(
    'foo_repository' => $er
));
```

The `$options` array is passed to the `FooType::buildForm()` method, so `foo_repository` should then be available in this method like so:

```
$er = $options['foo_repository'];
```

**Symfony 4 and 5:**

Symfony Form Types are services so you can use dependency injection:

```
class FooType extends AbstractType
{
    private $entityManager;

    public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $entityManager)
    {
        $this->entityManager = $entityManager;
    }

    private function getFooRepository(): FooRepository
    {
        return $this->entityManager->getRepository(Foo::class);
    }

    ...
}
```

or inject specific repository:

```
class FooType extends AbstractType
{
    private $fooRepository;

    public function __construct(FooRepository $fooRepository)
    {
        $this->fooRepository = $fooRepository;
    }

    ...
}
```

Comment: I cannot do so, because my `foo` property is not defined as any relation (`one-to-one` or any other) because of the relation is defined in very difficult way that doctrine currently doesn't support. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9123264/how-to-specify-several-join-conditions-for-11-relationship-in-doctrine-2 -- here is the question that explains the case

Comment: Sorry I didn't specify such significant details in the very first question revision, +1 for the help anyway. Any other thoughts?

Comment: Hi. No problem. I might have read your question too quickly anyway! I'd suggest `$this->buildForm($type, $entity, array('repository' => $er))` in your controller to pass the repository class as an option to your form, but I guess given your question you are looking to avoid this.

Comment: actually yes - currently I pass the repository instance using `LocationType::__construct()` and actually I cannot get how to use `$options` in `buildForm` (haven't seen any use-cases for it, so time to google now).

Comment: I might have an example of that actually. I'll dig it out and update my answer.

Comment: Yep, find that - it is the third arument of `Controller::createForm`. Thanks for the idea

Comment: The third argument is a array options to a form, we cant pass anything to this instance. I think that the constructor is a better solutions. :(

Comment: I should note that `getEntityManager()` is now deprecated in favour of `getManager()` recent versions of Symfony2.

Comment: As Cloudson noticed, you cannot just pass any custom parameter in the 3rd param for createForm(). 
But, it can be easily solved, as mentioned here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36999251/261332
That also seems better to me, than passing additional params to the Form class.

Comment: Hi @userfuser - thanks for the feedback. Yeah, the question quite old now so I'm guessing some things have changed in the form framework since it was posted. In any case, I'd probably have some very different opinions about how to answer it now - for example, it would be cleaner to set up the form as a service and wire up the entity manager as a constructor argument.