# Symfony 3 createForm with construct parameters

Tags: php, symfony

Since Symfony 2.8, you can only pass the FQCN into the controller createForm method. So, my question is, how do I pass construct parameters into the form class construct when I create the form in the controller?

< Symfony 2.8 I could do (MyController.php):

```
$this->createForm(new MyForm($arg1, $arg2));
```

Symfony 2.8+ I can only do (MyController.php):

```
$this->createForm(MyForm::class);
```

So how can I pass in my construct arguments? These arguments are provided in the controller actions so I can't use the "Forms as services" method...

Answer (score 20, accepted):

simply:

```
$this->createForm(MyForm::class, $entity, ['arg1' => $arg1, 'arg2' => $arg2]);
```

which is actually how it should have been done prior to 2.8 anyway.

**edit**

based upon your comment, you need to set up the default values in the class type itself:

```
public function configureOptions( OptionsResolver $resolver ) {
    $resolver->setDefaults( [
      'arg1' => null,
      'arg2' => null,
    ] );
}
```

Comment: This is incorrect, I get the following error: The option "passwordRequired" does not exist. Defined options are: "action", "allow_extra_fields", "attr", "auto_initialize"...

Comment: its not incorrect, you need to specify default options in the type class.