# Warning: Missing argument 1 for BannerType::__construct()

Tags: php, symfony

How to pass parameters to custom form type in controller with createForm methode in symfony3 ?
The parameter is "type"
In BannerType.php :

```
public function __construct($type){
    $this->type = $type;
}

public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class' => 'Banner\BannerBundle\Entity\Banner',
        'type' => null,
    ));
}
```

In BannerController.php :

```
$form = $this->createForm(BannerType::class, $entity, array(
    'typee' => $type,
));
```

Comment: You have typo in createForm parameter: 'typee' instead of 'type'.

Comment: Thanks but it's a typo
No influence

Answer (score 0):

You are not passing any argument when the object is created. That's why you got this message. The type parameter you can get from options variable that is available in buildForm method.

Here's an example of your form class:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $myType = $options['type'];
    if ($myType == NULL){
        // TODO: 
    }
}

public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class' => 'Banner\BannerBundle\Entity\Banner',
        'type' => null,
    ));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question was already on StackOverflow. You can read it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36999017/symfony-3-createform-with-construct-parameters) .I think you need to remove `__construct` function, because from `Symfony 2.8` you have to pass a string `FormType::class` to createForm method, not the instance of the object and this string is probably handled later as a constructor without any parameters. Then it should work :)

Answer (score 0):

When you want to pass some arguments into `FormType`'s contructor and be able to instantiate it via `createForm`, you need to register it as a service with a proper `form.type` tag like this:

```
# src/AppBundle/Resources/config/services.yml
services:
    app.form.type.banner:
        class: AppBundle\Form\Type\BannerType
        arguments:
            - '%type%'
        tags:
            - { name: form.type }
```

But this lets you pass only arguments that are available in service container, which are other services, parameters etc.

What you want to do actually doesn't make sense. You can't expect to get a param in constructor in `FormType` class, but pass it via third argument of `createForm()`, which is designed to take options, not constructor's arguments. It looks like you're trying to do that in a wrong way, but I would need to have more code and know what you're trying to do to tell you how it should be done.